# Get textContent of contenteditable element before change (or `beforeinput`)

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, addeventlistener

I have `<ol contenteditable=true>` elements and I want to add an eventListener so that *before* any changes in any `<li>` of these lists, the original `textContent` (that is, the text prior to any alterations) is pushed to `var alterations = []`.

I have tried using `addEventListener("beforeinput", ...`, as follows:

```js
window.alterations = [];

window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('main').addEventListener("beforeinput", () => {
    alert('event listened!');
    window.alterations.push(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.textContent);
    
    console.log(window.alterations);
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
<section id="main">
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ol>
</section>
</body>
```

But `beforeinput` does not seem to work on contenteditable elements (as the above code shows, the callback function is not executed). Only the `input` event works as argument to `addEventListener`, but then is too late, since one letter was already inputted or deleted from the original text.

*Question*: how can I get the original text of the element about to be changed via `contenteditable`? For example, if I type in the "First" `<li>` something else, like "not First", how can I push the original `textContent` (=== just "First") of the `<li>` to the `alterations` array?

---

**EDIT:** I think this is a browser issue. `beforeinput` works in Chromium based browsers, but not in Firefox based browsers (like Firefox and PaleMoon). My quickfix was to use `keydown` instead of `beforeinput`. This code works in all browsers:

```
 for (let x of document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]')) {
   x.addEventListener('keydown',() => {
     let originalText = window.getSelection().anchorNode.textContent; 
     console.log(originalText);
   });
```

But this has the unfortunate problem of triggering every time *any* key is pressed, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>. I tried `keypress` instead of `keydown`, but my Chromium based browser didn't trigger on deletions and any "move up/down/left/right/" keys pressed will also trigger the code. I guess I can handle these exceptions one by one with `charcode`, but is there no other way than using `keydown`?

Comment: `beforeinput` works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/hh7c9jn7/ ... there appears to be some error in your initial script code, as when just add the listener it works.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right. Maybe it's a browser issue. I upgraded Firefox to v. 59 and now a lot of my original code is not working correctly as I tried to debug it in XAMPP. So I changed to PaleMoon, and it didn't work. But refreshing it seems to work, maybe I forgot to save or something. I'm closing the browser and testing it again, if it works I'll close the question

Comment: @LGSon could you please clarify one thing for me? When you run my snippet code, does it work for you?

Comment: Just rechecked - it doesn't work in PaleMoon, I'm going to write a new script and test it in Firefox. But I tested it in a Chrome offshoot, here `beforeinput` works!

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work, it give the following error message: `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",` ... and I used Chrome for my testing

Comment: @LGSon Thanks! Sorry about that! Forgot to close the parentheses

Comment: Regarding the _triggering every time any key is pressed_ issue, so does `beforeinput` if you toggle back and forth to the element. One solution would be to set a custom property, e.g. `element.read_old_value = true` and check that before capture the old text.

Comment: @LGSon This behaviour is modified for contenteditable, if I'm not mistaken https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input . In `contenteditable` elements, the `input` event is only triggered when they are changed (so keyboard buttons "up", "down", "left", "right" don't trigger it). But on a second thought, it really isn't hard to change `keydown` handler to catch only the charcodes I want

Comment: In your question snippet it fires every time I push a key (but arrow keys), using Chrome, so you need a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this here should work:

```js
window.alterations = [];

window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('main').addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    //0 == delete in PaleMoon, 46 == delete in other browsers

    /* ALT is needed for some characters, like § and º, but to exclude ALT, META, etc.:
    if (event.altKey || event.metaKey) {return;} */

    if (event.key.length === 1 || ["Enter", "Delete", "Backspace"].includes(event.key)) {
      //when Ctrl is pressed, trigger only if Ctrl+V or Ctrl+X and ALT is not pressed:
      if (event.key.toLowerCase() !== 'v' && event.key.toLowerCase() !== 'x' && event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) {return;}

      alert('event listened!');
      window.alterations.push(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.textContent);

      console.log(window.alterations);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <ol contenteditable="true">
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
    </ol>
    <ol contenteditable="true">
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
    </ol>
  </section>
</body>
```

And this seems to be best in terms of compatibility, since I'm starting to think each browser has a different response to `beforeinput` (and maybe to `keydown` without a handler). I downloaded a Chromium based browser to test it and the results seem different than from Chrome.

*EDIT*: I replaced `event.which` for `event.key`, since the former is deprecated and works unreliably in different browsers.

Remaining problems:

1. If user repeatedly types `~~~` or `´´´´`, etc., this will not be
   handled.
2. <del>If user copies the text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), or uses another similar shortcut while `<li>` is focused, then event will unwillingly be triggered, since it listened to `c`.</del> [fixed thanks to @trysis comment]

Comment: For problem 2, you can look at `event.ctrlKey`. There are other flags for `Alt` and `Meta`.

Comment: @trysis Thanks! I'm updating the code to reflect that

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3165 to check when `beforeinput` will be more readily available to other browsers than Safari and Chrome